# ping TOS values

Tags: windows-server-2008, ping, windows-command-prompt

Windows Server® 2008 offers

```
ping -v TOS         Type Of Service (IPv4-only)
```

Trying to figure out what they mean I came that far that this has to do with IPv4's "Type of Service" Field – and that the use of this field was completely redefined and renamed at least one time and that it was/is most widely used experimentally (source → https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_of_service).

Question: What **TOS** values can be defined for `ping -v TOS` in Windows Server® 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `ping -v` **TOS** *… Beginning in **Windows 7, this option no longer functions** but still exists for compatibility reasons (source: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/p/ping-command.htm).*

Both Microsoft Windows 7 and Server 2008 are based upon NT 6, which seems to explain this.

---

Still I wonder why on a site from 2012 on `ping` this issue from 2007 onwards isn't mentioned (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961503.aspx)